# How are beams arranged in a continuous concrete beam structure?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, beam

[image: The problem related to this question]

I am posed with this problem, where I am tasked to design multiple structural beams supporting a concrete slab. As a disclaimer, this problem is merely an exercise instead of a homework or a test, and I already have the solution to this.

The question here states that there are *three equal spans*, meaning logically there should be 4 longitudinal beams spanning 4 meters, each placed on the 4 support columns supporting each side of the three spans.

[image]

However, the wording for the calculation "1st and 3rd mid spans" implies that there are **THREE**  beams lying in the **middle** of the span, instead of **four** beams lying at the **four** slab supports. The arrangement with **three** beams seem illogical, given that sections of the slab resting above this structure will be left unsupported. My question is, how are each structural beam arranged with the specifications given in mind?

[image]

This arrangement is what I have in mind after hours of searching my notes, youtube videos, and lecture recordings, but at this hour I have no way of verifying it myself.

EDIT: The solution to this problem provides different reinforcements for 1. a T-beam for the mid-span of 1st and 3rd spans 2. another T-beam the mid-span of the second span 3. A rectangular beam the interior supports, which I presume are the ones spanning over the three spans.

Can anyone verify if the arrangement i have in mind is correct, and if there are any misconceptions in my understanding?

Comment: I don't see a fault with your reasoning/understanding. What does the solution tell you? Can't you get a better understanding from that?

Comment: Yes, the last statement of arrangement is illogical, especially the wording "midspan".